# Show that for A and B, a language J exists such that A $\leq_T$ J, B $\leq_T$ J

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I am working on theory of computation problems, and I came across this one:

Show that for A and B, a language J exists such that $A \leq_T J$, $B \leq_T J$

The only $J$ I can think of for the moment is the language that uses a $TM$ $N$ which contains a recognizer $M1$ for $A$, and another recognizer $M2$ for $B$. $N$ uses oracle $J$ to check if input $x\in A U B$. If $J$ accepts, then it means that either $M1$ or $M2$ will halt, so $N$ can now simultate $M1$ and $M2$ simultaneously.

But I think there should be a simpler way to solve this..... any help?

Answer (score 2):

Just define $J$ as $A\oplus B = \{m \mid m =2k \text{ if } k \in A, \text{ and }  m =2k+1 \text{ if } k \in B \}$. Then $k \in A$ is decided by querying $2k \in A\oplus B$, and $k \in B$ is decided by querying $2k+1 \in A\oplus B$. Thus $A \leq_T A\oplus B$, $B \leq_T A\oplus B$.

This result is well known in the theory of computability. It establishes the least upper bound on the lattice of the Turing degrees of $A$ and $B$.